# Symfony\Component\Form\Form::handleRequest performance raises eyebrows

Tags: php, forms, symfony-forms, symfony

My question is, why is the handleRequest method inordinately slow in relation to the other operations in the request? HandleRequest takes almost as long as rendering the template. There is no database or Doctrine ORM involved in my Entity, it is simply a plain PHP class being used to bind user data to the form. I have put some reasonable validation on the entity, but even removing the validation annotation does virtually nothing to improve performance of this method.

I'm using Symfony 3.0.6 and PHP 7.0.7

[image]

**Controller**

```
public function postSearchAction(Request $request, $page = null)
{
    $this->setRequestPage($request, $page);
    $formData = new SearchRequest();
    $this->startTimeline("building form");
    $searchRequestForm = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, $formData, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('api_search_post'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));
    $this->stopTimeline("building form");

    $this->startTimeline("handle request");
    $searchRequestForm->handleRequest($request);
    $this->stopTimeline("handle request");

    if ($searchRequestForm->isValid()) {
        $formData = $searchRequestForm->getData();
        $this->startTimeline("build service request");
        $searchRequest = $this->get('search')->buildRequest($formData);
        $this->stopTimeline("build service request");

        if ($formData->getSearchType() === SearchRequest::TYPE_VEHICLE) {
            $search = $this->get('search')->getVehicle($searchRequest, $this->getStopwatch());
        } else {
            $search = $this->get('search')->getStorage($searchRequest, $this->getStopwatch());
        }
    } else {
        $search = $searchRequestForm;
    }

    $view = $this->view($search, 200)
        ->setSerializationContext($this->getSerializationContext())
        ->setTemplate("RestApiBundle:Search:postSearch.html.twig")
        ->setTemplateVar('search')
        ->setTemplateData(array(
            'form' => $searchRequestForm->createView()
        ));

    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

**Form**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('location', TextType::class)
        ->add('page', HiddenType::class, ['required' => false])
        ->add('searchType', ChoiceType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Search Type',
            'choices' =>[
                'Storage' => SearchRequest::TYPE_STORAGE,
                'Vehicle' => SearchRequest::TYPE_VEHICLE
            ]])
        ->add('squareFoot', ChoiceType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Unit Size',
            'placeholder' => 'Unit Size',
            'choices' => [
                '5\' x 5\''   => 25,
                '5\' x 10\''  => 50,
                '5\' x 15\''  => 75,
                '10\' x 10\'' => 100,
                '10\' x 15\'' => 150,
                '10\' x 20\'' => 200,
                '10\' x 25\'' => 250,
                '10\' x 30\'' => 300,
                'Default' => 0
            ]])
        ->add('sort', ChoiceType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Sort By',
            'placeholder' => 'Sort By',
            'choices' => [
                'Distance'  => SearchRequest::SORT_DISTANCE,
                'Price'     => SearchRequest::SORT_PRICE,
                'Rating'    => SearchRequest::SORT_RATINGS,
                'Default'   => SearchRequest::SORT_DEFAULT
            ]])
        ->add('moveInDate', DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'required' => false
        ])
        ->add('filterClimateControlled', CheckboxType::class, [
            'value' => 'true',
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Climate Controlled'
        ])
        ->add('filter24HourAccess', CheckboxType::class, [
            'value' => 'true',
            'required' => false,
            'label' => '24 Hour Access'
        ])
        ->add('filterDriveUpAccess', CheckboxType::class, [
            'value' => 'true',
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Drive Up Access'
        ])
        ->add('search', SubmitType::class);
}
```

**Entity**

```
class SearchRequest
{

const SORT_DISTANCE = 'distance';
const SORT_PRICE = 'price';
const SORT_RATINGS = 'ratings';
const SORT_DEFAULT = 'default';

const TYPE_VEHICLE = 'vehicle';
const TYPE_STORAGE = 'storage';

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $location;

/**
 * @var int
 * @Assert\Type(
 *     type="numeric"
 * )
 */
protected $page = 1;

/**
 * @var double
 * @Assert\Type(
 *     type="numeric"
 * )
 */
protected $squareFoot;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this.getSort() in this.getSortList()",
 *     message="Invalid sort type."
 * )
 */
protected $sort;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this.getSearchType() in this.getSearchTypeList()",
 *     message="Invalid search type."
 * )
 */
protected $searchType;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\Date()
 * @Serializer\Type("DateTime")
 */
protected $moveInDate;

/**
 * @var boolean
 * @Assert\Type(
 *     type="bool"
 * )
 */
protected $filterClimateControlled;

/**
 * @var boolean
 * @Assert\Type(
 *     type="bool"
 * )
 */
protected $filter24HourAccess;

/**
 * @var boolean
 * @Assert\Type(
 *     type="bool"
 * )
 */
protected $filterDriveUpAccess;


public function getSortList()
{
    return [
        null,
        self::SORT_DISTANCE,
        self::SORT_PRICE,
        self::SORT_RATINGS,
        self::SORT_DEFAULT
    ];
}

public function getSearchTypeList()
{
    return [
        self::TYPE_VEHICLE,
        self::TYPE_STORAGE
    ];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of software! I wonder if "xdebug" would be helpful? The other thing I might check is the logs in the Dev environment  `var/logs/dev.log`.

Comment: Do you have logs available? Can you post them somewhere (not here)?

Comment: For example at [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: Short, general answer: abstracting things raises complexity and costs time. Despite your form being quite simple there are a lot of things happening behind the scenes to allow more-complicated use cases, which even if not needed, contribute to execution time because of their checks or generic design allowing for them.

Comment: Hi did you add any var_dump or print_r in this page ?

Comment: I don't think it's very long, but if you're more interested in what's happening in that time you could just set a break point and step through each action. For a more general view you could have a look at the [framework events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html). Each of these will have both Symfony listeners and listeners from each bundle your project depends on that do a lot behind the scenes when the controller is determined, the response returned etc..

Comment: You can try using https://blackfire.io/ to see what's slow. We actually found out that creating UUIDs using ramsey\uuid took ~ 60% of our request time. I would have never guessed it.

Comment: @TomášFejfar and everyone else. I'm  here asking for answers, not to ask how to troubleshoot problems with a framework that I don't even contribute to. Sensio has lots of staff and talent already dedicated to debugging their own framework. If I had questions on how to troubleshoot performance of someone else's framework, I would have asked that question. I've already done the work to show that the performance degrade happens during the execution of a core Symfony Framework module. I'm not here to offer free help to their team.

Comment: The thing is that the issue might not be with the framework :) It could potentially be with your code . And you can never tell until you profile your code.

Comment: @TomášFejfar, actually, yes, I CAN tell. You can see, in my question, if you bothered to read it, that I've traced the performance degrade to a method in a core Symfony framework module. The profiling I did in the SCREENSHOT in my question, clearly shows that.

Comment: Oh, sorry it seems that I didn't describe it clearly enough and we have different ideas of what profilling means. You cannot be sure that what's happening inside is actually only symfony code. There could be some attached events being fired for example. Probably they are not, but you cannot be sure. Some of the classes may not be in composer autoloader for one reason or another causing disk IO or million other causes you'd never think of specific to your machine and/or code.